# Insert object in MS PowerPoint from MS Excel file with placeholder for the user profile dir like %userprofile%

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, environment-variables

We're syncing a folder with our selfhosted collaboration suite to the local PC of the users in their userprofile (e.g. `C:\Users\MyUser\MyFolder`). Some users use the *insert object* function to link e.g. diagrams from Excel files to PowerPoint as [documented here](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/office/einf%C3%BCgen-eines-excel-arbeitsblatts-in-powerpoint-0690708a-5ce6-41b4-923f-11d57554138d).

The problem: They link to their own userprofile dir, e.g. a link to `C:\Users\MyUser\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsx`. This link works on the user *MyUser*, but not on *MyOtherUser*. So my idea is to hse `%userprofile%` as placeholder, which resolves to the correct profile directory, depending which user is logged in. But it seems that PowerPoint doesn't properly resolve env vars like `%userprofile%` because when I use this variable, It throws an error that those file is not accessable or its filename is invalid:

[image]

This only happens with the `%userprofile` env variable: `%userprofile%\MyFile.xlsx` doesn't work, where `C:\Users\MyUser\MyFile.xlsx` doesn't work. Both are POC files.

#### Is there a way to use placeholders in the path for inserting objects in MS Office (especially PowerPoint)?

I know it's not a very clean solution and including office files can lead to security issues, but currently I see no better alternatives. From a long term perspective, we 're lookin to migrate the data in a database, where it belongs imho (so we don't need to mess with including office files).

Comment: If the value of the original %userprofile% variable were known, a bit of VBA could change it to the current %userprofile%. One possible approach would be to have the user who creates the OLE object in the first place run a macro that "tags" the object with the current %userprofile%. This would give a later "fix it" macro something to work with.